# Constraint in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

In the table `Semester`

```
Id             title           Year
ـــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ
 1             first           2012
 2             second          2012
```

How can I define a constraint for column `title` to allow only:

- first
- second
- Summer

Comment: Why don't you create a Master Table for Title and from the Front End can use DropDown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [const_name] 
CHECK  ([title]='first' OR [title]='second' OR [title]='Summer')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
   ADD CONSTRAINT title_value CHECK (title IN ('first', 'second', 'Summer'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Semester(
id int,
title varchar(50),
[year] int,
check  ( title in('first','second','Summer'))
)
```